# Select one column from a row in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am trying to do a simple query to get a unique result back in hibernate here is my code.

```
public String getName(Integer id) {
     Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
     String name = (String)session.createSQLQuery("SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id = :userId").setParameter("userId", id).uniqueResult();
     return name;
}
```

The name that is being returned is stored as HTML text that includes html syntacx language. I think this is what is causing the problem but it doesnt make sense I just want to return it as a string.

It is only happening on this one field name, I can get every other field in the row but this one it gives me the error.

I am getting an exception. The exception I am getting is

> No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException

How do you query for a specific column on a row in hibernate?

Comment: That looks fine. What is the exception?

Comment: just updated it with the exception. @Robby Pond

Comment: What dialect are you using? What's the type of "name"? mysql text?

Comment: yes mysql text is what I am using.

Comment: @Robby Pond updated - So the problem is that inside of the name field I have html that is wrapped around the name. I dont know why this would make a difference as it is all stored as a string. I escaped the string before inserting it into the DB so all characters have been escaped.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution, apparently Java has not type that can be mapped to Text fields so you have to add a scalar solution below: Thanks for the help

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id = :userId").addScalar("name", Hibernate.TEXT).setParameter("userId", id).uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Then that should work. Use the [Type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/type/Type.html) hibernate annotation.

Add

```
@Type(type="text")
```

To your mapping.

Comment: Sorry for being such a newbie but @Type in my model gives me an error. I have included javax.persistence.* but it has not annotation of @Type

Comment: Updated answer. Type is part of Hibernate.

Comment: including org.hibernate.type.* does not allow me to use the @Type annotation. I also tried @Column(name="name", columnDefinition="TEXT") but that did not work either.

Comment: okay I found it, it is in org.hibernate.annotation.type, however this still did not fix the problem.