# Before Insert in many-to-many table hibernate selects to many columns

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got two Entities `Customer` and `Product` with relation `many-to-many`.

`

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "customer_products",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="product_id")}) 
    @CollectionId(
            columns = @Column(name="id"),
            type = @Type(type="long"),
            generator = "native"
    )
    public Collection<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    public void addProduct(Product product){
        this.products.add(product);
    }
    public void setProducts(Collection<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
```

`

I want to add Customer product

`

```
    Customer customer = (Customer)session.load(Customer.class, new Long(1));
    Product product = (Product) session.load(Product.class, new Long(1));
    customer.addProduct(product);
    session.persist(customer);`
```

What the code does is, it selects all columns from table `Customer` and `Products` and insert only `ids` from those tables into `customer_products` table. Is there a way to select only `ids` from above tables?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to retrieve separate entity data from columns without instantiating whole entity objects with JPA/Hibernate.

This would work perfect with one-to-one, but not sure about many-to-many relation:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> q = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<Customer> c = q.from(Customer.class);
q.select(cb.array(c.get("id"), c.get("products").get("id")));

List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
for (Object[] result : results) {
  System.out.println("Customer id: " + result[0] + ", Product id: " + result[1]);
}
```

Still worth a try, might get you on the right track. [Look for more information on JPQL and CriteriaBuilder queries.](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select)

BTW, if you could provide reason why do you need to do that, maybe we could then provide an alternative solution from fresh perspective, because now we can't see why is this required.

Comment: I thought it would be better in terms of performance. It sends and receives less data. Am I wrong or it is negligible?

Comment: But what are you going to do with IDs?

Comment: I understand it this way. When invoking a method `addProduct` in `Customer class` hibernate add a row into `customer_products`table and the only columns it adds are `ids` from `Customer` and `Products` tables. So basically I don't need the rest of data which is selected.

Comment: But its the way things work in database, column is described as foreign key to primary key. When you add Product, it adds itself to the Products table and then adds relationship with Customer to Customer_Products table, it is normal. Or there is something I don't get?

Answer (score 0):

It's only inserting id into the table because that's all that you've set on the entity and you don't have any `not null` constraints on the other columns.  There's no way to deal with `Customer` or `Product` directly and get only their ids without their other data.  That's just part of ORMs.

You can, however, use a [native SQL query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-creating) to select single pieces of data from the database.  [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969258/select-one-column-from-a-row-in-hibernate/4970203#4970203) provides a nice example of SQLQuery usage as well.

***Edit***

After re-reading your question, I realized that you were saying ids were being inserted into the `customer_product` table.  So my first paragraph isn't really correct.  It's only inserting ids because you're just adding products to customers and that's your cross reference table.

However, the solution is the same.  If you want to select only ids from `customer` or `product`, you need to use an SQL query.  If you're wanting to select ids from `customer_product` directly (which would be kind of strange) you either need to use an SQL query or create a `CustomerProduct` object (which would be even more strange).